# Shared Memory Buffer Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

A little bit of a background about my status:

I'm currently using OVH Advance 5 Server (AMD Epyc 7451 - 24 c / 48 t - 128 GB Memory - 450x2 GB SSD) and I was wondering the specifications I should be using for Postgresql.

I'll be using multiprocess running 24 Python scripts with 24 different pools (using asynpg to connect), and I usually use up about 40 GB of RAM or so - that means I have around 88 GB to work with.

Before I've never really touched any of the settings for Postgres; what kind of values should I be using for:

Shared Memory / Max Connections / Random Page Cost?

Reading up on it, it says it's recommended that Shared Memory should generally take up about 25% of the free RAM - but other sources say 2 - 4 GB is generally the sweet spot point, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `shared_buffers`: start with 25% of the available RAM or 8GB, whatever is lower.

  You can run performance tests to see if other settings work better in your case.
- `max_connections`: leave the default 100. If you think that you need more than 50 connections, use the connection pooler pgBouncer.
- `random_page_cost`: if your storage is as fast with random I/O as with sequential I/O, use a setting of 1.1. Otherwise, stick with the default 4.

Comment: About the pooling - I'm using asyncpg. Whenever I instance a pool with 10 max_workers, it seems to cause up 10 connections from what I can see? Or is each pool considered 1 connection.

Comment: That are 10 database connections.